# HTML5 video tag doesn't works in iPad?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, video

I am trying to play a video using an HTML5 `<video>` tag but its not working in iPad/iPhone with `autoplay`.

```
<video class="newvideo" autoplay loop preload >
    <source src="video/snow.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/snow.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video/snow.webm" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason videos would not play on iPad unless you  set the controls="true" flag.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply Webruster. what i want is., it should play on load (autoplay) rather than click the control.